# Can undead that you have reanimated wait inside a portable hole?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, undead

Assuming I cast the appropriate levels of spells to keep them under my control, could my undead that have already been reanimated stay in a portable hole as they don’t need to breathe or sleep?

I don’t see any reason that they can’t, but this seems like a extremely easy work around to what is normally a large problem.

Comment: (Clarified question title; this got onto HNQ and I thought it should be more explicit)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  The reason every necromancer doesn't use it all the time is that most wizards don't own a portable hole.